# Swap the type of link depending on model object

Tags: wicket

I'm at complete loss how to proceed further:

I have panel with a DropDownChoice and a submit button next to it. Depending on the selected value of the DropDownChoice (Obtained upon the firing of a OnChangeAjaxBehavior attached to it, the submit button needs to either replace the whole panel with a different one, OR become an ExternalLink.

Currently, the code looks like that:

```
public class ReportSelectionPanel extends Panel {
   protected OptionItem selectedOption ;
   public ReportSelectionPanel(String id) {
       super(id);
       IModel<List<OptionItem>> choices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel() {
        // Create a list of options to be displayed in the DropDownChoice
       } ;

       final IModel<OptionItem> optionModel = 
            new PropertyModel<OptionItem>(this,"selectedOption") ;

       final DropDownChoice<OptionItem> options = 
            new DropDownChoice("selectChoice",optionModel,choices) ;

       // I don't know what the button should be... Plain Button? A Link?
       final Component button = ???

       options.add( new OnChangeAjaxBehavior()  { 
             protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                  if ( selectedOption.getChild() == null ) {
                        // button becomes an ExternalLink.
                        // A new window will popup once button is clicked
                   } else {
                      // button becomes a Something, and upon clicking,
                      // this ReportSelectionPanel instance gets replaced by
                      // an new Panel instance, the type of which is
                     //  selectedOption.getChild() 
             }
       } ) ;
```

I'm really not quite sure what the commented lines should become to achieve the result. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it's nicer to keep just one button and just react differently depending on the selected option:

```
final Component button = new AjaxButton("button") {
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (selectedOption.getChild() == null) {
            PopupSettings popup = new PopupSettings();
            popup.setTarget("'" + externalUrl + "'");
            target.appendJavascript(popup.getPopupJavaScript());
        } else {
            ReportSelectionPanel.this.replaceWith(new ReportResultPanel("..."));
        }
    }  
};

// not needed if options and button are inside a form
// options.add( new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() { } ) ;
```

Comment: That does the trick! Thanks! (The method to overload was onSubmit), and I had my component hierarchy a little loopy, but I think I'm in better shape now!